# Can you run Highcharts with dynamic data in angular JS with require.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, highcharts

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="thumbnail alert-info alert alert-dismissible fade in">
            <p class="lead text-center"> Our Dynamic KPI</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/cad.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

JS script

```
$.get('scripts/dataCAD.csv', function(csv) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        data: {
            csv: csv
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CAD'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Component in angular 2

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'cad',
    templateUrl: './cad.html'
})
export class cadcomponent {

}
```

I have other scripts working in my application by using `require.js` and they are all working perfectly however I am not getting an error in the console for this highcharts page but there is No data displayed.

I did look at this [FAQ link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#faq)  however i couldn't make it work. if anyone has any experience with highcharts and angular 2 any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a live demo, like Plunker?

Comment: I ended up just inputting the data myself. I will try and create a plunkr when i have some free time. What I would like to do is have the charts read the data from an excel or csv file. I cannot make the plunkr with the current data set as it has company proprietary information